# Show that for all natural $a$, $2008\mid a^{251}-a$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How to show, that for all natural $a$ coprime to 2008 the following occurs:  $2008\mid a^{251}-a$?

This means, that $a_{251} \equiv_{{}\bmod 2008} a$, right?

It's obvious if $a\mid 2008$.

In the other case I'm totally at a loss.

I thought about using Euler totient function but that's obviously doesn't apply here, since $2008$ is not prime.

Comment: We need to modify the question a bit. Doesn't work for example for $n=2,4,6$.

Comment: You need $(a,n) = 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin $(a,8)=1$ suffices.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Happy coincidence that I didn't state what $n$ is lol. But yes, that works out.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Carmichael.27s_theorem

Comment: By the way, Euler's theorem works whether or not the modulus is prime. In fact, it can be seen as an extension of Fermat's little theorem to non-prime moduli. So you *can* say that $a^{\phi(2008} \equiv 1 \mod 2008$ for $\gcd(a, 2008) = 1$.

Comment: Are you sure about the exercise? Do you want to show that $2008~|~a^{251}-a$ or $2008~|~a^{251}$?

Comment: @frabala The first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $2008 = 8\cdot 251$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem it is necessary and sufficient to show $a^{251}\equiv a\pmod 8$ and $a^{251}\equiv a\pmod {251}$. The second is true for all $a$ by Fermat's little theorem.
The first is true for odd $a$ or if $8\mid a$, but otherwise it is not!